# Django/CSS Icon and form input in same column

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I am having a problem putting icon from font awesome and form input in the same column.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      <div class="row pt-3">
         <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg">{{ form.username }}</i>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

With the code above, it looks a screenshot bellow:
[image: how it looks like now]

I would like to look like the image bellow:

[image: what I would like]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **better** to deal with boxes with **flexbox** rather than row for more alignment flexibility.

Try the following code

```
<div class="form-group">
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.media }}
      <div class="d-flex pt-3">
         <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg mr-2 "></i>{{ form.username }}
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help.If this answer your question you can accept answer thankfully.